# Broadcast to only one web socket in room using ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I am using ActionCable to provide Browser Notification which is easy to implement. The problem is coming when a user has open the multiple tabs in the browser and I need to send the data to only one tab i.e to only one WebSocket in user room. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time a new connection is made we will create a new room. So for example when the user is making a new connection we can give the room name as users:user_id:some_unique_random_string which may be equal to users:user_id:123j123b1h2b1j23bh12b3 and when the same user makes another connection by opening another tab we will also do the same and create a separate room.
Now one thing the ActionCable provides is that we can find all the room name followed by any prefix.

Lets the user has made three connections and their rooms are users:128:123n1jh123ko9876, users:128:asdas23412cs1234, users:128:asni9202h5i3jens then we can obtain these room name using ActionCable also.

```
user_id = 128
pubsub = ActionCable.server.pubsub
channel_with_prefix = pubsub.send(:channel_with_prefix, RoomChannel.channel_name)
channels = pubsub.send(:redis_connection).pubsub('channels', "#{channel_with_prefix}:users:#{user_id}:*")
```

Now the channels is an array consisting of the rooms name.

So `puts channels`

```
["chatapp_production:users:128:123n1jh123ko9876", "chatapp_production:users:128:asdas23412cs1234", "users:128:asni9202h5i3jens"]
```

This is how we can find all the rooms related to a single user without using any external database and API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Isolating a single pub/sub client isn't directly possible with the pub/sub approach, because the whole idea is that publishers have no knowledge of subscribers.

However, there are two common ways to solve this:

1. to use a different named channel per connection, saving the named channel in the database and forwarding all messages to that specific named channel (i.e. saving the channel `user-ID-TIMESTAMP` in the database and using it as the target connection).
2. another, somewhat more reliable approach (though more complex) is to send the message to all clients but create a race condition that allows only a single client to receive the actual message. This would look something like this:

   - server sends "you have a message" to all clients.
   - client polls "undelivered" messages from the server.
   - server locks the message pool or uses a database transaction in order to retrieve undelivered messages and mark the messages as delivered. The server sends the undelivered messages to the client (optionally setting an ACK timeout).
   - a single client connection receives the undelivered messages the rest get an empty array of messages (since they were all delivered to the other client) or receive a "delivered" flag so the data is updated but no notification is raised.
   - (optional) the client sends and ACK.
   - (optional) the server marks the message delivery as complete. If no ACK was received before "timeout", server unmarks delivery and resends the "you have a message" message.

Good luck!